# Manifest retrieves fields that belongs to managed package and more

Tags: salesforcedx, package.xml, continuous-integration, scratch-org-definition-file, manifest

I would like to retrieve only the necessary data from my production org (which has several installed managed packages). But when I retrieve the data in my manifest (package.xml) from org in order to push to my scratch org I get several errors, like:

> Cannot create a new component with namespace: i.

The previous error is because the Account object has some custom field from a package, like ***i__DaysSinceLastMail__c***

This is my package.xml definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Opportunity_Triggers</members>
        <members>OppDocAutomationHandler</members>
        <members>OppDocAutomationHandler</members>
        <members>DocusignGetAccessToken</members>
        <members>AttachmentExt_Trigger</members>
        <members>TestOppDocAutomationHandler</members>
        <members>OpportunityAssignment_Helper</members>
        <members>MockHtttpResponse</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Opportunity_Trig</members>
        <members>AttachmentExt_Trig</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Docusign_Integration_Detail.Docusign_Production_Details</members>
        <members>Docusign_Integration_Detail.Docusign_Sandbox_Details</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account.Contact_Count__c</members>
        <members>Account.Is_Default_Prospect_Bucket__c</members>
        <members>Account.OppCountUSA__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Program_Recommendation_Type</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

What would be a good package.xml definition and a good scratch org definition file in order to start implementing a package development model and continuous integration for my org? I prefer to retrieve only the necessary components in order to test or solve a feature from my org, instead of retrieving all the components which can throw almost 1000 errors when pushing to a scratch org

Any help would be greatly appreciated